# Script which launches another application will bring it down on exit

Tags: bash, nohup

I have a script which does launch another application using `nohup my_app &`, but when the initial script dies the launched process also goes down. As per my understanding since since it has been ran with `nohup` that should not happen. The original script also called with nohup.

What went wrong there?

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior.  I created one script that runs "nohup xterm &", and ran this script using nohup.  The terminal opened and stayed open.

Comment: @VaughnCato are you sure your first script stopped working? you invoke X11 application. There are differences. Try doing same on tty1 or remote server with any another app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very reliable script that has been used successfully for years, and has always terminated after invoking a nohup uses this construct:

nohup ${BinDir}/${Watcher} >${DataDir}/${Watcher}.nohup.out 2>&1 &

Perhaps the problem is that output is not being managed?

Comment: Actually i did not mention it here, but i do handle outputs, stdout goes to /dev/null stderr goes to a file. Maybe i should try also disown second process? But i have no control on that from first script. Is it possible?

Comment: In the case I refer to, the parent process always terminates cleanly (is not killed).  akluth's answer seems quite relevant.  I've not tested what happens if I were to keep the parent script running and then kill it.  Is there a reason why the parent script cannot just terminate?

Answer (score 1):

nohup does not mean that a (child) process is still running when the (parent) process is killed. nohup is used f.e. when you're connecting over ssh to a server and there starting a process. If you log out, the process will terminate (logging out sents the signal SIGHUP to the process causing the process to terminate), using nohup avoid this behaviour and you're process is still running when you logged out.

If you need a program which runs in the background even it's parent process has terminated try using daemons.

Comment: Any advice on how to use daemons? Should i use `daemon` util for that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends what `my-app` does - it might set its own signal mask.  You probably know that `nohup` ignores the hang-up signal SIGHUP, and this is inherited by the target program.  If that target program does its own signal handling then it might be setting SIGHUP to, for example SIG_DFT - the default action (which is to die).

To check, run `strace -f -o out` or `truss -f -o out` on the command.  This will give you all the kernel calls in the file called 'out'.  You should be able to spot the signal mask being changed if it is.